# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Some fields are missing (optional or mandatory)

Tags: java, apache-camel, bindy

I am trying to create a fixedfile reader using Apache Camel Bindy but am getting exception.Please help me to find the solution.Without header and footer which is working well.

**Update:**
File is small to understand now and public is added

**File Content:**

```
101-08-2009
30A9
20A9
60A9
40A9
10A9
50A8
9000000002
```

**New Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Some fields are missing (optional or mandatory), line: 2
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.BindyFixedLengthFactory.bind(BindyFixedLengthFactory.java:295) ~[camel-bindy-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.fixed.BindyFixedLengthDataFormat.createModel(BindyFixedLengthDataFormat.java:294) ~[camel-bindy-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
```

**Exception:**

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper can not access a member of class com.camel.examples.OrderHeader with modifiers ""
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.newInstance(ObjectHelper.java:1686) ~[camel-core-2.19.1.jar:2.19.1]
```

**Router:**

```
// @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        Comparator<Order> comparator = new Comparator<Order>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Order o1, Order o2) {
                return o1.getOrderNr() - o2.getOrderNr();
            }
        };

       DataFormat bindy = new BindyFixedLengthDataFormat(Order.class);
        from("file:C:/Users/workspace/SampleProjects/in?delete=true")
                .routeId("ValidateFile-Post2Q")

                .unmarshal(bindy).split(body().sort(comparator));
```

**Model Java classes:**

```
    @FixedLengthRecord(length = 4, paddingChar = ' ', header = OrderHeader.class, footer = OrderFooter.class)
public class Order {

    private @Link OrderHeader header;
    private @Link OrderFooter footer;

    @DataField(pos = 1, length = 2)
    private int orderNr;

    @DataField(pos = 3, length = 2)
    private String clientNr;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return orderNr + clientNr + header + footer;
    }

    public OrderHeader getHeader() {
        return header;
    }


    public void setHeader(OrderHeader header) {
        this.header = header;
    }


    public OrderFooter getFooter() {
        return footer;
    }


    public void setFooter(OrderFooter footer) {
        this.footer = footer;
    }

    public int getOrderNr() {
        return orderNr;
    }

    public void setOrderNr(int orderNr) {
        this.orderNr = orderNr;
    }

    public String getClientNr() {
        return clientNr;
    }

    public void setClientNr(String clientNr) {
        this.clientNr = clientNr;
    }
}

    @FixedLengthRecord
    public class OrderFooter {

        @DataField(pos = 1, length = 1)
        public int recordType ;

        @DataField(pos = 2, length = 9)
        public String numberOfRecordsInTheFile;

        public String toString() {
            return recordType + ":" + numberOfRecordsInTheFile;
        }

        public int getRecordType() {
            return recordType;
        }

        public void setRecordType(int recordType) {
            this.recordType = recordType;
        }

        public String getNumberOfRecordsInTheFile() {
            return numberOfRecordsInTheFile;
        }

        public void setNumberOfRecordsInTheFile(String numberOfRecordsInTheFile) {
            this.numberOfRecordsInTheFile = numberOfRecordsInTheFile;
        }   
    }

    @FixedLengthRecord
    public class OrderHeader {
        @DataField(pos = 1, length = 1)
        public int recordType = 1;

        @DataField(pos = 2, length = 10, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
        public Date recordDate;

        public String toString() {
            return recordType + ":" + new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(recordDate);
        }

        public int getRecordType() {
            return recordType;
        }

        public void setRecordType(int recordType) {
            this.recordType = recordType;
        }

        public Date getRecordDate() {
            return recordDate;
        }

        public void setRecordDate(Date recordDate) {
            this.recordDate = recordDate;
        }
    }
```

**Dependencies:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-spring-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel xquery support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-saxon</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Camel JMS support and ActiveMq -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-bindy</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-restlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-flatpack</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hawtio dependency - a lightweight web console to monitor and manage 
            application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
            <artifactId>hawtio-springboot</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.hawt</groupId>
            <artifactId>hawtio-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a setter and a getter to the "header" and "footer" in your Order class ? (Just took a look at the doc and your code doesn't look wrong .. )

Comment: Thanks for reply, with header and footer setters and getters also it is not working.

Comment: I guess it's the same error ? what if you set header and footer private rather than package protected ? I would have believed ObjectHelper needed a Bean-like object to instantiate it ...

Comment: Even with private header and footer in Order.class same issue comes.

Comment: Maybe one class per file? (unlikely)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a quick look at the camel bindy component tests and I could not find one that combines @FixedLengthRecord(header,footer ) with @Link

One possible workaround to your issue could be to

1. Remove @Link from your header and footer fields in Order e.g

   ```
    @FixedLengthRecord(length = 4, paddingChar = ' ', header = OrderHeader.class, footer = OrderFooter.class)
       public class Order {

       private OrderHeader header;
       private  OrderFooter footer;
   }
   ```

   2.Then the header and footer are successfully processed by bindy and added in the exchange as headers("CamelBindyFixedLengthHeader","CamelBindyFixedLengthFooter") so with a processor you can set them to the order header,footer fields afterwards
   e.g

   ```
   .unmarshal(bindy).split(body()).process(exchange -> { 
   Order order = exchange.getIn().getBody(Order.class);

                    order.setFooter((OrderFooter)exchange.getIn().getHeader(BindyFixedLengthDataFormat.CAMEL_BINDY_FIXED_LENGTH_FOOTER,Map.class).get(OrderFooter.class.getName())); 
                      order.setHeader((OrderHeader)exchange.getIn().getHeader(BindyFixedLengthDataFormat.CAMEL_BINDY_FIXED_LENGTH_HEADER,Map.class).get(OrderHeader.class.getName()));
               });
   ```

Related camel unit test [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/3505e718db48cc0d8be5b47f6c4030c958d93a5f/components/camel-bindy/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/dataformat/bindy/fixed/headerfooter)

Comment: Thanks a lot which works well, thanks again +1 with acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your POJOs are public classes. Its not your POJO class that instantiate another class, its camel-bindy / camel-core and that code runs in `org.apache.camel` packages, and cannot rely on package visible access to POJOs. So bottom line, keep it public so its standard Java beans.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but some other exception is coming as java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Some fields are missing (optional or mandatory).Is there something I missed in config?

Answer (score 0):

The camel-bindy sometimes tries to bind to the wrong model object.

A solution that I found on web was to try to put each model object in a  different package.(not a clean solution but good enough to know where the issue lies - with our code or with library)

I was getting a similar exception & although this solution didn't work for me but maybe you can give it a try.

You can see the details, here:
[Camel-bindy exception](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Bindy-component-more-than-one-model-object-per-package-td4793295.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I moved my related models(Content,header and footer) in a separate package also clearly stated main model in DataFormat as DataFormat bindy = new BindyFixedLengthDataFormat(Order.class); but no use same issue.